# android phone doesn't ring anymore after setback to normal

Tags: android

Hi in my code i need to set phone ring to silence i do that by this code

```
 private void silenceRinger()
    {
       for (;;)
        {
           try
            {
                this.telephonyService.silenceRinger();
                return;
            }
            catch (Throwable localThrowable) {
                localThrowable.printStackTrace();
            }
            try
            {
                AudioManager localAudioManager = (AudioManager)this.mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

                localAudioManager.setRingerMode(0);

                return;
            }
            catch (Exception localException)
            {
                localException.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

and i need to set back to normal ring mode for that i use this code

```
 private void setRingerMode(int paramInt){
        try {
            AudioManager localAudioManager = (AudioManager)this.mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            oldRingerMode = localAudioManager.getRingerMode();
            localAudioManager.setRingerMode(paramInt);
            return;
        }catch (Exception localException) {

            localException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

but problem is when i set back to normal mode my phone do not ring anymore more interesting thing is my phone isn't in silence mode and i can see volume is in maximum. 
can anyone help me about this problem?

**Update**
i found my problem and that was a logical problem.
what i want to do is create simple callblocker app for that i have broadcast reciever and in it i check phone number for blocking numbers but problem is when calls coming i get one ring then block number. and that's because checking which make some delay for avoid from this i mute ringer then check the number and then unmute ringer but current call do not ring again.
**so my question is how to avoid from first ringer before block the call ? or how can we set mute to call and unmute during current call?**

Comment: Are you using the correct int to set it back to normal? I would suggest using the constant fields instead of magic integers: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#RINGER_MODE_NORMAL

Comment: yes i set 2 to paramInt like i said my phone Appearance not in silence but when a call coming dosent ring